# Grey Background in R When Using qcc (quality control charts) Plot

Tags: r, plot, background

I'm having a problem where my graph is always on a light grey background which looks awful in LaTeX. I've tried using `par(bg=NA)`, `par(bg="white")` which is what everyone suggests but that literally does nothing...

Here's the code:

```
# install.packages('qcc')
library(qcc)
nonconforming <- c(3, 4, 6, 5, 2, 8, 9, 4, 2, 6, 4, 8, 0, 7, 20, 6, 1, 5, 7)
samplesize <- rep(50, 19)
control <- qcc(nonconforming, type = "p", samplesize, plot = "FALSE")
warn.limits <- limits.p(control$center, control$std.dev, control$sizes, 2)
par(mar = c(5, 3, 1, 3), bg = "blue")
plot(control, restore.par = FALSE, title = "P Chart for Medical Insurance Claims", 
     xlab = "Day", ylab = "Proportion Defective")
abline(h = warn.limits, lty = 3, col = "blue")
v2 <- c("LWL", "UWL")  # the labels for warn.limits
mtext(side = 4, text = v2, at = warn.limits, col = "blue", las = 2)
```

Comment: Please try to provide code that is self-sufficient for reproducing (here it lacks the data)

Comment: Done, thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out `?qcc.options()` -- specifically, the `bg.margin` option. The following will change your plot to have a `lightgreen` background (note: probably not a good choice for LaTeX, but it illustrates the point):

```
library(qcc)
nonconforming <- c(3, 4, 6, 5, 2, 8, 9, 4, 2, 6, 4, 8, 0, 7, 20, 6, 1, 5, 7)
samplesize <- rep(50, 19)

old <- qcc.options()  # save the original options
qcc.options(bg.margin = "lightgreen")
par(mar = c(5, 3, 1, 3))
control <- qcc(nonconforming, type = "p", samplesize, plot = "FALSE")
warn.limits <- limits.p(control$center, control$std.dev, control$sizes, 2)
plot(control, restore.par = FALSE, title = "P Chart for Medical Insurance Claims", 
     xlab = "Day", ylab = "Proportion Defective")
abline(h = warn.limits, lty = 3, col = "blue")
v2 <- c("LWL", "UWL")  # the labels for warn.limits
mtext(side = 4, text = v2, at = warn.limits, col = "blue", las = 2)
qcc.options(old)  # reset the old options
```

[image: Plot]

Comment: Ahh brilliant, didn't think that it would be a qcc option. Thanks for the edit too, I'll try to format it better next time.

Comment: @HarrisonO'Neill No problem. Took me a bit to find too. Sometimes it's easiest to dig through the source code -- I typed `plot.qcc` to find out what it was doing and saw a line: `par(bg = qcc.options("bg.margin")...` and that led me to looking up `qcc.options` in the docs.

Comment: Any idea how I would go about hiding the CL and LCL? I have to produce a Range Chart and we don't typically draw the center line or lower control limit.

Comment: @HarrisonO'Neill not off hand. I'd either open up another question or poke around the `qcc` docs or google for tutorials on the `qcc` package.